# Postfix collect all recieved mails in one account

Tags: linux, email, postfix-mta

I need to catch all mails sent to "@example.com" and redirect them to a single mail account. 

So if a mail was sent to test@example.com or testtest@example.com, both mails should be redirected to allmails@example.com.

I couldnt find a way yet to solve this problem - anyways i'm new to postfix and arent sure in which part of the documentation to look for this.

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com, as it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
@example.com  catchallaccount
```

into `/etc/postfix/virtual` and make sure there's a

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Comment: Thanks alot! How can i access these emails now - is 'catchallaccount' a linux user ?

Comment: it's the name of whatever account you want all the mails to go to.